# How to pass multiple values to "with_items" through ad-hoc command?

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-module, ansible-ad-hoc

Here is the example ansible-playbook, if I want to pass the values of {{ item.first }} and {{ item.second }} through ad-hoc command from the terminal.

How can we do it ?

Thanks in advance..

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Here we are providing a list which have items containing multiple 
    debug:
      msg: "current first value is {{ item.first }} and second value is {{ item.second }}"
    with_items:
      - { first: lemon, second: carrot }
      - { first: cow, second: goat }
```

Comment: Do you want to run this task/play, taking value from command line instead? If its the ad-hoc mode, you won't be able to use `with_items` and `item`.

Comment: Does [variables in Ansible ad-hoc commands](https://serverfault.com/a/1027026/448950) answer your quesstion?

Comment: thank you @seshadri_c can you please let me know what needs to be changed in the playbook. So, that the above task/play could be run from the command line. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to loop your `debug` task by passing the values from command line (or anywhere else), you will need to use a variable for the task (e.g. `with_items: "{{ my_var }}"`).

There are many ways to supply value to variables, but for this specific requirement, we can use [`--extra-vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line).

Considering a playbook `myplaybook.yml` as below:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Here we are providing a list which have items containing multiple
      debug:
        msg: "current first value is {{ item.first }} and second value is {{ item.second }}"
      with_items: "{{ my_var }}"
```

Can be run by passing this variable on the command line as:

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -e '{my_var: [{first: lemon, second: carrot}, {first: cow, second: goat}]}'
```

Do note the other ways (linked above) using which variables can be supplied and use them if they are more efficient than this approach.