# How to overwrite loop var on launching ansible-playbook

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I have this playbook to create multiple users with loop

```
- name: creation des users
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: admin
    append: yes
    state: present
    password: "{{ 'some_password' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    update_password: on_create
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  register: createaccount
```

and me vars/main.yml

```
# vars file for linux_users_saas_create
users:
  - username: user1
  - username: user2
  - username: user3
  - username: user4
```

Now i want to be able to overwrite this loop var to create once one other user that is not in the list because is a temporay user

like this : ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "username=user5"

Can you help me please on that

Comment: From your extend d explanation, I get that you don’t want to override here but you want to extend the existing list with an extra username, correct?

Comment: In fact the final point is to launch playbook with rundeck and be able to overwrite the loop_vars with either 1 user or either multiple users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like that :

```
- name: "Create User"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "root"
  user:
    name: "{{ user_name | default(item.username) }}"
    shell: "/bin/bash"
    groups: "admin"
    append: yes
    state: present
    password: "{{ 'some_password' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    update_password: on_create
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  register: "createaccount"
```

And past this command :

```
ansible-playbook tonplaybook.yml -i inventory.yml -e "user_name=user5"
```

By default item.username is used to create user with your vars file :D

Ive lint ur code ET voila :D

Et pour aller plus loin

Kevin is right, each users gonna have the same password so you can do that to generate random password for each one :

```
- name: "Create password"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "root"
  set_fact:
    sa_pass: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}"
  register: random_password

- name: "Create users"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "root"
  user:
    name: "{{ user_name | default(item.username) }}"
    shell: "/bin/bash"
    groups: "admin"
    append: yes
    state: present
    password: "{{ random_password.sa_pass }}"
    update_password: on_create
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  register: createaccount
```

A plus dans le bus fratélo

Answer (score 0):

If it is only temporary, do not overwrite it.
Just set a default empty `temp_user`, and overwrite that.

```yaml
name: "{{ item.username + temp_user | default('') }}"
```

Then on the cli, you can add them:
`ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "temp_user=user5"`

-- edit --

And btw, it would be cleaner to define your list as:

```yaml
users:
  - user1
  - user2
```

And do note that every password is equal for every user created, not really secure I would say.

Comment: I'm sorry, i did what you suggest but it dosen't work, the playbook still read my var file and not the extra var
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username + temp_user | default('') }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: admin
    append: yes

Comment: in fact with verbose option the playbook concatenate the username var user1 with the temp_user var user2
so the user created was user1user2

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution i found on another topic :

I keep my playbook has it is but the had-hic command looks like this :

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -e '{users: [{username: user5}]}'
```

Ref:
[How to pass multiple values to "with_items" through ad-hoc command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490203/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-with-items-through-ad-hoc-command)

Comment: No problem... u can keep how to generate random password with ansible 

See you :D